# Найти количество дней прошедших от момента рождения до определенной даты

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Надо найти количество дней прошедших от момента рождения до определенной даты(надо учитывать високосные года) ....
Никак не могу написать рабочий код(Pascal).

```
сonst
mans:array[1..12]of integer=(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30,31);

var
y,m,d,y1,m1,d1:integer; good:boolean;
procedure prov(var y,m,d,y1,m1,d1:integer; var good:boolean );
begin
readln(y,m,d);
readln(y1,m1,d1);

good:=(y<y1)and(m>0)and(m<=12)and(m1>0)and(m1<=12)and(if(y mod 4=0)and(m=2) then (d>0)and(d<=29)else if (m mod 2=0)then (d>0)and(d<=31)else(d>0)and(d<=30))and (if (y1 mod 4=0)and(m1=2) then (d1>0)and(d1<=29)else if (m1 mod 2=0)then

(d1>0)and(d1<=31)else(d1>0)and(d1<=30));
if good=true then writeln('ok');
if not good then writeln('no');
end;
procedure sch(y,m,d,y1,m1,d1:integer);
var dni,gd:integer;
er:real;
gd:=y1-y;
er:=gd div 4;
dni:=er*366+(gd-er)*365+abs()*30+abs(d1-d);
writeln(dni);
end;
begin

prov(y,m,d,y1,m1,d1,good);

if good then  sch(y,m,d,y1,m1,d1);

readln;`
end.
```

Comment: @kuvschinov-eugeny, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно привести обе даты: рождения и текущий день к количеству миллисекунд. Вычеcть одно из другого. А потом разницу привести к дням. 1 день = 1000 (миллисекунд) * 60 (секунд) * 60 (минут) * 24 (часа). За високосные года отвечает встроенный календарь стандартной бибилиотечки. Самостоятельно это считать в большинстве случаев не нужно.
Если это учебное задание, то мой ответ не подойдёт :)